# How does C get the array offset right for an array of strings?

Tags: c, arrays, string

I'm doing something for class where I want to use a different format string based on certain conditions. I defined it like so:

```
const char *fmts[] = {"this one is a little long", "this one is short"};
```

later, I can use

```
printf(fmts[0]);
```

or

```
printf(fmts[1]);
```

and it works.

Is the compiler doing something for us? My guess is that it would take the longest string and store all of them aligned like that. But I'd like to know from someone who knows. Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It does it the same way as for any other data type. An array of "strings" is actually an array of character pointers, which *all* have the same size. So, in order to get the right address for the *pointer*, it multiplies the index by the size of an individual element, then adds that to the base address.

Your array will look like this:

```
      <same-size>
      +---------+
fmts: | fmts[0] | ------+
      +---------+       |
      | fmts[1] | ------|--------------------------+
      +---------+       |                          |
                        V                          V
                        this one is a little long\0this one is short\0
```

The characters for the strings themselves are *not* stored in the array, they exist elsewhere. The way you have it, they're usually stored in read only memory although you can `malloc` them as well, or even define them as a modifiable character array with something like:

```
char f0[] = "you can modify me without invoking undefined behaviour";
```

You can see this in operation with the following code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
const char *fmts[] = {
    "This one is a little long",
    "Shorter",
    "Urk!"
};
int main (void) {
    printf ("Address of fmts[0] is %p\n", (void*)(&(fmts[0])));
    printf ("Address of fmts[1] is %p\n", (void*)(&(fmts[1])));
    printf ("Address of fmts[2] is %p\n", (void*)(&(fmts[2])));

    printf ("\n");

    printf ("Content of fmts[0] (%p) is %c%c%c...\n",
        (void*)(fmts[0]), *(fmts[0]+0), *(fmts[0]+1), *(fmts[0]+2));
    printf ("Content of fmts[1] (%p) is %c%c%c...\n",
        (void*)(fmts[1]), *(fmts[1]+0), *(fmts[1]+1), *(fmts[1]+2));
    printf ("Content of fmts[2] (%p) is %c%c%c...\n",
        (void*)(fmts[2]), *(fmts[2]+0), *(fmts[2]+1), *(fmts[2]+2));

    return 0;
}
```

which outputs:

```
Address of fmts[0] is 0x40200c
Address of fmts[1] is 0x402010
Address of fmts[2] is 0x402014

Content of fmts[0] (0x4020a0) is Thi...
Content of fmts[1] (0x4020ba) is Sho...
Content of fmts[2] (0x4020c2) is Urk...
```

Here you can see that the actual addresses of the array elements are equidistant - `0x40200c + 4 = 0x402010`, `0x402010 + 4 = 0x402014`.

However, the values are not, because they refer to differently sized strings. The strings are in a single memory block (in this case - it's not necessary by any means) as shown below, with the `*` characters indication start and end of individual strings:

```
         |  +0 +1 +2 +3 +4 +5 +6 +7 +8 +9 +a +b +c +d +e +f +0123456789abcdef
---------+-------------------------------------------------------------------
0x04020a0| *54 68 69 73 20 6f 6e 65 20 69 73 20 61 20 6c 69  This one is a li
0x04020b0|  74 74 6c 65 20 6c 6f 6e 67 00*53 68 6f 72 74 65  ttle long.Shorte
0x04020c0|  72 00*55 72 6b 21 00*                            r.Urk!.
```

Comment: you must have lots of fun drawing diagrams using ASCII chars haha

Answer (score 3):

**fmts** points to pointers to char. It does not point to the strings themselves.

In other words: the difference in addresses of `fmts[0]` and `fmts[1]` is the size of the type `char *`.

Comment: False! You'd have to cast `&fmts[0]` to a `char *` pointer for your arithmetic to work. C pointer arithmetic adjusts for type!

Comment: hope you don't mind, I recast your code into text so it wouldn't suffer the problems of C type scaling.

Answer (score 3):

You don't have an array of strings. You have an array of *pointers to strings* or, more precisely, an array of pointers to first characters of strings. All pointers have the same size, so the issue with determining offset simply does not arise.

If you really wanted to have an array of strings, you have to declare something like that

```
const char fmts[][64] = { "this one is a little long", "this one is short" };
```

i.e. you'd have to declare an array of arrays. In this case it would become your responsibility to specify the sufficient fixed size for your actual string arrays (`64` in my example), and that value would determine the fixed offset from one string to the next one in the array.

As you correctly noted in your question, the minimum size you can specify in this example is determined by the longest string in the array. However, the compiler will not calculate it for you. You have to explicitly specify it yourself.

Comment: Damn you wrote almost the exact same thing as I did, a few seconds earlier!

Answer (score 2):

The answer is that you don’t have an array of strings *per se*, you have an array of pointers to `char`s. The pointers are all the same size, `printf()` just dereferences them.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the compiler will make the first pointer point to the first character of the first string, and the second pointer point to the first character of the second string.

Since it is "an array of pointers to character", so each pointer can point to any places, no need to be equal length or anything.

Answer (score 2):

You did not declare an array of strings. You declared an array of pointers to strings. An array of strings would look like:

```
char fmts[][40] = {"this one is a little long", "this one is short"};
```

and as you can see, you had to specify the maximum length as the second array dimension (only the first dimension of a multi-dimensional array can be determined implicitly in C).